# Is there a widely agreed upon beer ranking or competition?

Tags: taste

Is there one beer competition (or ranking) that is widely recognized as the "Superbowl" of beer competitions?  In that being the winner or rankings to come out of that competition are the standard to measure beers against.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some that claim this, such as the [World Beer Cup](http://www.worldbeercup.org/) - but like this one, these are mostly US only, so the range of beers is very limited - as well as generally charging to enter.

[The International Brewing Awards](http://www.brewingawards.org/news.php?did=32), now in it's 128th year is probably the best known global competition, with a truly international line-up (although this year the cask ales category was dominated by the UK)